# Logging Which Cell in Table Array Has Been Clicked With Event Listener

Tags: javascript

Perhaps a silly question, but I'm just starting to learn JS.

How would I log which table cell has been clicked with the following code (as an example).

```js
// Get array of td elements; 9 cells for game board
var board = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  console.log(board[i]);
  board[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(board[i]);
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>



  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Loggin either board[i] or [i] don't work; I always comes up as 9, and board[i] comes up undefined.

EDIT: Doing some digging, I managed to stumble across some things and throw them together to make them work.

I still don't honestly understand how it works, though.

```
function testf(i) {
  return (function(){
           console.log("you clicked region number " + i);
         });
}
// Trigger function cellClicked() when any table cell is clicekd
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  board[i].addEventListener("click", testf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are misinterpreting is that the statement variable `i` is block scoped. But variables initialized with `var` in JavaScript are function scoped. So at the time the event is fired the variable `i` is `9`, because the loop is finished.

With ES2015 you can replace `var` with `let` and you are done, because `let` initializes a variable with block scope:

```
for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  console.log(board[i]);
  board[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(board[i]);
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

But this only works in new Browsers or when you are transpiling your code to ES5 with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) for example.

You have to introduce a new scope for the `i` to keep the value of `i` for each iteration to make it work without `let`

```
function handleClick(i) {
  // function sets new scope for i
  return function() {
    console.log(board[i]);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  console.log(board[i]);
  board[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the i variable inside the click and replace it with this. As you can see here-

```
board[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the event to the function to get a reference to the event's target (the td element in this case), then get the innerText or innerHtml, like this:

```
board[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move your function outside of the loop to save recreating the same function multiple times. And then, inside the function, simply use the `this` keyword to access the clicked element:

```js
function log(){
  // this is passed from the EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // method:
  console.log(this, this.textContent);
}

// Get array of td elements; 9 cells for game board
var board = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  board[i].addEventListener("click", log);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you could delegate the event-handling to the ancestor `<table>` element:

```js
function log(e){
  // this is passed from the EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // method, but here refers to the <table> element, to find
  // the clicked <td> element we need to look at the
  // target property of the 'event' (here 'e') also passed 
  // from the addEventListener() method:
  console.log(this, e.target, e.target.textContent);
}

// retrieving the first/only <table> element on the page,
// adding the event-listener for the click-event and
// binding the log() function as the event-handler:
var board = document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', log);
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is well known mistake.

> Creating closures in loops: A common mistake
>   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

and this is fix for your problem

```
window.onload = function () {
    function logEvent(a, b) {//closure function
        return function () {
            console.log(a);//values from outer function
            console.log(b);
        }
    }
    var board = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        console.log(board[i]);
        var log = logEvent(board[i].innerHTML, i);//take values when they exist
        board[i].addEventListener("click", log);
        //board[i].addEventListener("click", logEvent(board[i].innerHTML, i));//this way is also possible
    }
}
```